# Getting sibling data from nested Json object

Tags: json

First, thank you for any help you can provide!  I've been away from coding for awhile and am having some trouble solving a problem I have with some dynamic JSON data and hoping someone can help me understand where I am stuck.

I am pulling some data in node using node-fetch and returning a JSON object with their data.  Heres the structure that returns.
[image: JSON Object]

I need to pull the assets: # based on its sibling template id and I cannot seem to figure it out.  I can pull the data if I use  `data.data.templates[0].assets`, but the template ID is not always going to be in the same[0] spot in the structure depending on how many templates the user has.  I have checked a few posts here and thinking I may need to use JSON Expressions but I am not really getting how to make it work.

`data.data.templates[templates == '210537'].assets);`  feels like I am close but no cigar yet.

Can anyone point me to a post that might help me understand what I am missing!?  The extra nesting is throwing me off and I am so confused at this point!

I've looked over this post [json sibling data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016304/json-sibling-data) and a few others around the web but still stuck.  Also it's a Node project and I am fetching the data from the web using the node-fetch module.  I don't think that matters but just a little more info incase it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use this kind of syntax, I suggest [jsonpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath)

Example:

```
const jp = require("jsonpath");

const cities = [
    { name: "London", "population": 8615246 },
    { name: "Berlin", "population": 3517424 },
    { name: "Madrid", "population": 3165235 },
    { name: "Rome", "population": 2870528 }
];

const population = jp.query(cities, "$[?(@.name =='London')].population");
console.log(population);
//[ 8615246 ]
```